# Time/date difference with client and server?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry if this has been asked before or if I'm not able to explain in a great way. I've spent hours trying to wrap my head around the issue and I just can't seem to fix this issue. The code is working fine locally, but when I upload it to my server there seems to be some sort of issue with how the server handles/checks differences in time between server and client. Not sure exactly how or what to think. I'm also aware that I'm inserting data into pdo statements incorrectly, I don't care about that at the moment. I will tidy all this up at a later point.

The part of the application that I'm experiencing issues with is when it checks an active shipment (it's a sort of game). I want to compare the timestamp from the database with the current time to see if the time has passed. In the case that the arrival time is past, then I want to set the status of the shipment to 'delivered' as well as add the data to another table called 'storage'.

```
function check_active_shipment(){
    $pdo = pdo();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM shipments WHERE username LIKE '$username' AND status LIKE 'active' LIMIT 1");
    $statement->execute();
    $rows = $statement->fetch();
    $id = $rows['id'];

    if($rows['type'] == "purchase"){
      if(time() >= strtotime($rows['arrival'])){
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE shipments SET status='delivered' WHERE id LIKE '$id'");
        $statement->execute();

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO storage (username, crate_type_id, quantity) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $statement->bindParam(1, $username);
        $statement->bindParam(2, $rows['crate_type_id']);
        $statement->bindParam(3, $rows['quantity']);
        $statement->execute();
        //header("location:index.php");
      }
    }
    else if($rows['type'] == "sale"){
      if(time() >= strtotime($rows['arrival'])){
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE shipments SET status='delivered' WHERE id LIKE ?");
        $statement->bindParam(1, $id);
        $statement->execute();

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE username LIKE ?");
        $statement->bindParam(1, $username);
        $statement->execute();
        $user = $statement->fetch();
        $cash = $user['cash'] + $rows['value'];

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET cash=?");
        $statement->bindParam(1, $cash);
        $statement->execute();
        //header("location:index.php");
      }
    }
  }
```

Let me know if there is any information I'm missing to share.

Comment: Is your database hosted on another server? If so, is it hosted on a server with different time / timezone?

Comment: Everything is on the same server, files and database. I don't know what timezone it is, but considering the server is in Stockholm I assume Europe/Stockholm. Any ideas on how to find out the server/database timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would getting the time from the server, rather than using the time() function solve you problem.

Either do a separate query

```
SELECT NOW()
```

or add it to your existing query

```
SELECT *, NOW() as curtime FROM shipments WHERE .....
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this, but this worked wonders! Thank you PaulF!

Answer (score 0):

> Have you tried using the `DateTime` Class? Perhaps it behaves much like you had expected... Here's a snippet on how to use it in your case:

```
    <?php
        // ...SOME CODE...
        if($rows['type'] == "purchase"){
            // TRY USING DateTime CLASS
            $arrival    = new DateTime($rows['arrival']);
            $arrivalTS  = $arrival->getTimestamp();

            if(time() >= $arrivalTS){
                // REST OF THE CODE...
            }

        }else if($rows['type'] == "sale") {
            // TRY USING DateTime CLASS AGAIN
            $arrival    = new DateTime($rows['arrival']);
            $arrivalTS  = $arrival->getTimestamp();

            if (time() >= $arrivalTS) {
                // REST OF THE CODE...
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have tried using the DateTime class, although i didn't try it with getTimestamp. Unfortunately after just trying it I get the same result. It still seems like there is a difference in time somehow. Thank you for the reply though.